# Using preg_grep to find match

Tags: php, regex

I need server to return complete IDs that contain an integer(single digit or more) sent in by a user to find a match.
e.g I submit '5678', then server returns 12567891, 54356782, 90567811. 
Emphasis on '5678'. My code returns no results.

```
<?php
$per = array(456755643, 78567561, 443321, 33267554560, 44321122,   554367533, 3390);
$thr = 675;
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $jake = preg_grep(("/$thr+/", $per);
    foreach($jake as $value){
        print $value . br;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$jake = preg_grep(("/$thr+/", $per);` won't compile. Remove one `(`. The `+` is also redundant. Try just `$jake = preg_grep("/$thr/", $per);`

Comment: hi... just did. doesn't work. returns nothing.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/SCQarE

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$per = array(456755643, 78567561, 443321, 33267554560, 44321122,   554367533, 3390);
$thr = 675;
$jake = preg_grep("/$thr/", $per);
foreach($jake as $value){
    print $value . '<br>';
}

//result
456755643
78567561
33267554560
554367533
```

Comment: @harrid, working fine for 675 also updated my answer with results

Comment: @harrid in your array none value contain 5678 thats why its returning blank

Comment: hi... its meant to return integers that contain '5678' @Saurabh

Comment: ..in the code I sent it, it should return numbers that contain '675' e.g 67544, 886751, 46758.

Comment: Ok I just ID'd an error in my code. It works alright. Merci!